# Should electrons as tiny magnets, stick to a permanent magnet if in appropriate conditions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, electrons

Should electrons as tiny magnets, stick to a permanent magnet if in appropriate conditions? Why shouldn't the magnet collect them like tiny iron dust?I know they repeal each other but should a certain number of them touch the magnet? Is it,for example,possible collect those electrons from silk cloth after rubbing a glass bar? Would that electrons on the silk align their magnetic dipoles with the permanent magnet if we position the magnet close to the silk producing so a weak (fero)magnetic effect?